# How do I search a scanned PDF using vb.net, and then print it?

Tags: vb.net

I've been asked by the company I'm interning at to design a system that could search a scanned PDF file using the SO number and date as unique keys. How would I do this, as I believe a scanned PDF is not searchable?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you can't do this - at least not quite like that. You'd need to run the scanned PDF through an optical character recognition app first (there are plenty of free ones on the web) and convert it to text, at which point you can start manipulating data.